# Amazon EBS Django 404 Error. The requested URL / was not found on this server

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

So I finally finished my project, creating dads website, and followed these instructions to deploy it to ebs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

However, when I go to http://django-env.ethmrbkmgd.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/ I get the error:
       The requested URL / was not found on this server.

On my local server the website runs perfectly. After researching I discovered that people said it had to do with trailing back slashes in urls.py but this seemed to not fix it. Another person recommended to change allowed hosts to ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] but that has not work either. Here is my project layout

```
suliman_baldo

bin
include
lib
media_cdn
src
   .ebextensions
       django.config
   .elasticbeanstalk
       config.yml
   gallery
   main
   static
   suliman_baldo
       settings.py
       urls.py
   requirements.txt
```

My urls.py file is

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from main import views 


from django.conf.urls.static import static #testing
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns


urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'suliman_baldo.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', "main.views.home"),
    url(r'^index/', "main.views.home"),

    url(r'^aboutme/', "main.views.aboutme"),    
    url(r'^publications/', "main.views.publications"),    
    url(r'^archive/', "main.views.archive"),   
    url(r'^gallary', include('gallery.urls')),    
    url(r'^filer/', include('filer.urls')),


]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns +=  static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) 
    urlpatterns +=  static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here are the config files

django.config

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: src/wsgi.py
```

config.yml

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: django-env
environment-defaults:
  django-env:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: suliman_baldo
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: aws-eb
  default_platform: Python 2.7
  default_region: us-east-1
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: null
```

Comment: What nginx config is your EBS instance using?

Comment: You certainly don't need that slash in the pattern: it should just be `r"^$"`.

Comment: thanks for the heads up! not sure what nginx config is. It turns out the requirements.txt file was one level off from where it needed to be ! Sorry for the inconvenience, I even forgot to write it down on the directory.

Comment: Got the same issue even today following [AWS public documentation] (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-setup-venv) as it is. Though I got the following error in events "Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist" as well. Looks like the documentation is broken, followed this [medium article] (https://medium.com/@justaboutcloud/how-to-deploy-a-django3-application-on-elastic-beanstalk-python3-7-and-amazon-linux-2-bd9b8447b55) which worked perfectly.